# Не изменяются значения в косоли

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!

Есть такая вот простенькая программка.
Ее цель: прочитать файл(в файле хранятся числа разделенные пробелом), занести числа  в ArrayList, а потом из этого ArrayList-a вывести их на консоль. Программа постоянно проверяет - не было ли модификации файла? Если файл был изменен, то содержимое ArrayList-a обнуляется, а потом все заново считывается, заносится в ArrayList и выводится на консоль.

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    File file = new File("res/numbers.txt");
    long lastMod = file.lastModified(); //
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    read(br,numbers);

    //Был ли изменен файл?
    while (true){
        if(lastMod!=file.lastModified()){
            numbers.clear();                   //Чистим ArrayList
            read(br, numbers);                 //Заново считываем
            lastMod = file.lastModified();     //Обновляем дату модификации
        }
    }
}

public static void read(BufferedReader br, ArrayList<Integer> numb) throws IOException {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line," \"'!&?,.~");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
              numb.add(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
        }
    }
    for(Integer i: numb){
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}}
```

Вопрос вот в чем:

допустим, в файле были такие числа: 1 56 88 39 100  , программа их считала и вывела на консоль, она продолжает работать и ждет изменений файла

я вручную открываю файл, дописываю в конец ряда пробел и новое число 1000, сохраняю файл

консоль нам показывает: 1 56 88 39 100 1000 , т.е. все ок

**НО**, когда я захожу в файл и удаляю какое-либо число(закрываю-сохраняю), то на консоли ничего не происходит, ряд чисел остается без изменений

Почему так происходит? Как сделать так, чтобы работало нормально?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неправильно работаете с I/O, то есть с классом BufferedReader. Вот ваш код, исправленный:

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
    File file = new File("res/numbers.txt");
    long lastMod = file.lastModified();
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    read(file, numbers);

    // Был ли изменен файл?
    while (true) {
        if (lastMod != file.lastModified()) {
            numbers.clear(); // Чистим ArrayList
            read(file, numbers); // Заново считываем
            lastMod = file.lastModified(); // Обновляем дату модификации
        }
    }
}

public static void read(File file, ArrayList<Integer> numb)
        throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); //читаем файл заново каждый раз
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " \"'!&?,.~");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            numb.add(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
        }
    }
    br.close(); //не забываем закрыть поток ввода/вывода

    for (Integer i : numb) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(); //ну и перевод строки для красивости
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`BufferedReader` не предоставляет интерфейса для чтения с начала (но в данном коде это ваша вина). Поэтому, когда вы добавляете новые символы в файл, `BefferedReader` считывает то, что с оффсетом последнего уже считанного символа.

Поэтому у вас два пути:

1. Открывать файл каждый раз (не забывать его потом еще и закрывать), когда вы входите в цикл, тогда с помощью `BufferdReader` вы будете считывать все с самого начала (соответственно будут включены все изменения).
2. Использовать `RandomAccessFile`:

---

```
RandomAccessFile br = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
//...
while (true){
//....
    numbers.clear();                   //Чистим ArrayList
    br.seek(0);
    //....
}
```